# two dimentional arrays with html input tag

Tags: php, html

This is a table and i wrote a jquery to add more rows and delete rows. then i want to add this data to database as a array(1 array = 1 row). but here i cant get values. i used this code to see the output. `print_r($_POST['list']);` and the output is this one.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => lakith
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 456
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => lahiru
        )

)
```

But i want this type of out put. in here i input two raws. and i want to get 
two arrays. but according to html table in below i cant get this. the output what i can get is the above one

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [name] => lakith
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            ['id'] => 456
            ['name'] => lahiru
        )

)
```

This is my html page:

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST">
    <table id="tb1">
      <tr>
        <td> <input type="text" name="list[][i']" placeholder="1"></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="list[][name]" placeholder="2"></td>
        <td><input type='button' class='AddNew' value='Add new item'></td>
      </tr>

     </table

    </br>

    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Register">


    </form>
```

In here i wrote it to add some rows to table and delete that rows if i don't want.

Can u guys give me the solution? i tries to get a solution to fix this. but couldn't to find way to correct this. so please help me to correct this one.

Comment: Well, not a major flaw, and not certain if it was just a syntax mistake when you pasted your code, but you are not closing the `</table` properly, remember to add the last `>` to it.

Comment: i completely closed table. but here it is missing

Answer (score 0):

Your code is adding each field as a new array element to `list`:

```
<tr>
    <td> <input type="text" name="list[][id]" placeholder="1"></td>
    <!-- ---------------------------- ^^ -->
    <td> <input type="text" name="list[][name]" placeholder="2"></td>
    <!-- ---------------------------- ^^ -->
    <td><input type='button' class='AddNew' value='Add new item'></td>
</tr>
```

To organize the array like you're asking, you need to do something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td> <input type="text" name="list[row_one][id]" placeholder="1"></td>
    <!-- -------------------------------- ^^ -->
    <td> <input type="text" name="list[row_one][name]" placeholder="2"></td>
    <!-- -------------------------------- ^^ -->
    <td><input type='button' class='AddNew' value='Add new item'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> <input type="text" name="list[row_two][id]" placeholder="1"></td>
    <!-- -------------------------------- ^^ -->
    <td> <input type="text" name="list[row_two][name]" placeholder="2"></td>
    <!-- -------------------------------- ^^ -->
    <td><input type='button' class='AddNew' value='Add new item'></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: to add another rows i wrote a jquery so how i do this from jquery <script>
$('.AddNew').click(function(){
   var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
   row.find('input').val('');
   $(this).closest('tr').after(row);
   $('input[type="button"]', row).removeClass('AddNew')
                                 .addClass('RemoveRow').val('Remove item');
});

$('table').on('click', '.RemoveRow', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
</script>